# "ValueError: Unable to create tensor" when trying to train a hugging face transformer

Tags: python, tensorflow, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am trying to use the "visheratin/t5-efficient-mini-grammar-correction" pre-trained model for grammar correction and I would like to add my own training examples.

I've loaded the model:

```
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("visheratin/t5-efficient-mini-grammar-correction")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("visheratin/t5-efficient-mini-grammar-correction")
```

set the training arguments:

```
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./models",
    num_train_epochs=3,
    per_device_train_batch_size=8,
    learning_rate=3e-5,
    weight_decay=0.01,
)
```

and created the training data:

```
training_examples = [ ('input text 1', 'output text 1'), ('input text 2', 'output text 2') ]

train_data = []
for input_text, target_text in training_examples:
    input_ids = tokenizer.encode(input_text, return_tensors="pt", truncation=True, padding=True)
    target_ids = tokenizer.encode(target_text, return_tensors="pt", truncation=True, padding=True)
    train_data.append({
        'input_ids': input_ids,
        'attention_mask': torch.ones_like(input_ids),
        'labels': target_ids,
    })
```

but when I go to train:

```
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_data,
)
trainer.train()
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Unable to create tensor, you should probably activate truncation and/or
padding with 'padding=True' 'truncation=True' to have batched tensors with the same
length. Perhaps your features (`input_ids` in this case) have excessive nesting (inputs
type `list` where type `int` is expected).
```

I already have 'padding=True' and 'truncation=True' to tokenizer.encode() and as far as I can tell I do not have any excessive nesting in my features.

This is the full Traceback:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/ub_nbdev2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py:715, in BatchEncoding.convert_to_tensors(self, tensor_type, prepend_batch_axis)
    714 if not is_tensor(value):
--> 715     tensor = as_tensor(value)
    717     # Removing this for now in favor of controlling the shape with `prepend_batch_axis`
    718     # # at-least2d
    719     # if tensor.ndim > 2:
    720     #     tensor = tensor.squeeze(0)
    721     # elif tensor.ndim < 2:
    722     #     tensor = tensor[None, :]

ValueError: expected sequence of length 37 at dim 2 (got 44)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[104], line 1
----> 1 trainer.train()

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/ub_nbdev2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1501, in Trainer.train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval, **kwargs)
   1496     self.model_wrapped = self.model
   1498 inner_training_loop = find_executable_batch_size(
   1499     self._inner_training_loop, self._train_batch_size, args.auto_find_batch_size
   1500 )
-> 1501 return inner_training_loop(
   1502     args=args,
   1503     resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,
   1504     trial=trial,
   1505     ignore_keys_for_eval=ignore_keys_for_eval,
   1506 )

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/ub_nbdev2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1723, in Trainer._inner_training_loop(self, batch_size, args, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval)
   1720     self._load_rng_state(resume_from_checkpoint)
   1722 step = -1
-> 1723 for step, inputs in enumerate(epoch_iterator):
   1724 
   1725     # Skip past any already trained steps if resuming training
   1726     if steps_trained_in_current_epoch > 0:
   1727         steps_trained_in_current_epoch -= 1

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/ub_nbdev2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:628, in _BaseDataLoaderIter.__next__(self)
    625 if self._sampler_iter is None:
    626     # TODO(https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/76750)
    627     self._reset()  # type: ignore[call-arg]
--> 628 data = self._next_data()
    629 self._num_yielded += 1
    630 if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \
    631         self._IterableDataset_len_called is not None and \
    632         self._num_yielded > self._IterableDataset_len_called:

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/ub_nbdev2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:671, in _SingleProcessDataLoaderIter._next_data(self)
    669 def _next_data(self):
    670     index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 671     data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    672     if self._pin_memory:
    673         data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data, self._pin_memory_device)

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/ub_nbdev2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py:61, in _MapDatasetFetcher.fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     59 else:
     60     data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]
---> 61 return self.collate_fn(data)

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/ub_nbdev2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer_utils.py:696, in RemoveColumnsCollator.__call__(self, features)
    694 def __call__(self, features: List[dict]):
    695     features = [self._remove_columns(feature) for feature in features]
--> 696     return self.data_collator(features)

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/ub_nbdev2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/data/data_collator.py:249, in DataCollatorWithPadding.__call__(self, features)
    248 def __call__(self, features: List[Dict[str, Any]]) -> Dict[str, Any]:
--> 249     batch = self.tokenizer.pad(
    250         features,
    251         padding=self.padding,
    252         max_length=self.max_length,
    253         pad_to_multiple_of=self.pad_to_multiple_of,
    254         return_tensors=self.return_tensors,
    255     )
    256     if "label" in batch:
    257         batch["labels"] = batch["label"]

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/ub_nbdev2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py:2985, in PreTrainedTokenizerBase.pad(self, encoded_inputs, padding, max_length, pad_to_multiple_of, return_attention_mask, return_tensors, verbose)
   2982             batch_outputs[key] = []
   2983         batch_outputs[key].append(value)
-> 2985 return BatchEncoding(batch_outputs, tensor_type=return_tensors)

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/ub_nbdev2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py:210, in BatchEncoding.__init__(self, data, encoding, tensor_type, prepend_batch_axis, n_sequences)
    206     n_sequences = encoding[0].n_sequences
    208 self._n_sequences = n_sequences
--> 210 self.convert_to_tensors(tensor_type=tensor_type, prepend_batch_axis=prepend_batch_axis)

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/ub_nbdev2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py:731, in BatchEncoding.convert_to_tensors(self, tensor_type, prepend_batch_axis)
    726         if key == "overflowing_tokens":
    727             raise ValueError(
    728                 "Unable to create tensor returning overflowing tokens of different lengths. "
    729                 "Please see if a fast version of this tokenizer is available to have this feature available."
    730             )
--> 731         raise ValueError(
    732             "Unable to create tensor, you should probably activate truncation and/or padding with"
    733             " 'padding=True' 'truncation=True' to have batched tensors with the same length. Perhaps your"
    734             f" features (`{key}` in this case) have excessive nesting (inputs type `list` where type `int` is"
    735             " expected)."
    736         )
    738 return self

ValueError: Unable to create tensor, you should probably activate truncation and/or padding with 'padding=True' 'truncation=True' to have batched tensors with the same length. Perhaps your features (`input_ids` in this case) have excessive nesting (inputs type `list` where type `int` is expected).
```

Could someone please help me understand what could be causing this error?